# My Raspberry Pi crashed after pulling out USB drive from it

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card, boot-issues, backup

My Raspberry Pi's OS is Raspbian Stretch Lite. My Raspberry Pi crashed after pulling out USB drive from it. I'm not able to access it via SSH. I have connected the SD card of my Raspberry Pi to my Ubuntu PC and I found two partition of the SD card. One of them is `boot` and another is `rootfs`. In the `rootfs` partition, I've found all of my data in the Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to fix it and how?

**Update:** The `rootfs` partition disappeared that contained all of my data after reconnecting the card reader with my PC! Is it possible to get it back?

Comment: @TomasBy I used Raspbian Stretch Lite and only used it as a server and I did not use screen with it. And the `rootfs` partition suddenly disappeared after connection the card reader again with my PC. Is it gone forever?

Comment: `The rootfs partition disappeared` - you must've deleted the partition, as partitions do not self erase

Comment: Did the Windows PC offer the choice to reformat your SDCard because Windows couldn't read it? If you selected **YES** rather than **CANCEL** then Windows will have destroyed your ext4 filesystem. If Windows ever pops up that request for a Raspberry Pi SDCard the only sensible answer is **CANCEL**. Time to flash a new copy of Raspbian to your card - its contents have gone forever.

Comment: @Dougie The OP uses an Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Just to clarify: you attached the Card Reader with the SD Card to your Ubuntu PC and saw the rootfs partition. Then you pulled out the card reader and attached it again and the rootfs partition has gone?